# Text Search And Replacement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text, replace

I am working with visual basic and i'm creating a function which performs a search for each word that is entered into a richtextbox. As a word is being entered into `RichTextBox2` a search Is performed in `RichTextBox1` and the text is highlighted .

`RichTextBox1` and `RiochTextBox2` are read only , `RichTextBox2` is able to be written in via code while `RichTextBox1` has only default text (A directory of words). There is also `RichTextBox3` which holds a copy of `RichTextBox2's` text

```
RichTextBox3.Text = RichTextBox2.Text
```

this is the code for the function .

```
public class textsearch
Private intPosition As Integer

Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    generatekanji()

    '   Static intStart As Integer
    'used to select compare method
    Dim intStart As Integer
    Dim objType As Object
    Dim lastWord As String = RichTextBox2.Text.Split(" ").Last
    objType = CompareMethod.Text

    'set starting position to 1
    intPosition = 1
    'use the InStr function to look up a staring position of a search string in a given text box using objType (case-insensitive or case-sensitive)
    intStart = InStr(intPosition, RichTextBox1.Text, lastWord, objType) ' what it searches
    If intStart > 0 Then

        'set starting select position on a textbox and select the search string
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = intStart - 1
        RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = lastWord.Length 'highlights the searched word
        RichTextBox1.Select()

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

This is a very useful function but the main issues are

(1) because `RichTextBox1` is read only , you gear  the "ding" sound each time a search is being performed and it gets very annoying.

(2) I am unable to find a way to select the character  whenever a word is found , or how to replace the word in `RichTextBox3` with the character next to the searched word.

Could someone help with this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use this code the search word is highlighted with no dinging, in a readonly richtextbox:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SearchWord As String = RichTextBox2.text
    Dim SelStart As Integer = InStr(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchWord, CompareMethod.Text)
    If SelStart > 0 Then
        RichTextBox1.Select(SelStart - 1, SearchWord.Length)
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
        For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
            If line.Contains(SearchWord) Then
                RichTextBox3.Text = line.Split()(0)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm wondering if the dinging is coming from the generatekanji() routine.

Comment: nah generatekanji() is nothing really.
this code still causes a ding sound and it will search once with the method of searching i use which is a live search which searches foe every single word entered in richtextbox2 . so while richtextbox2 text is changed it will do the search.

Comment: I got one the problem fixed 
thanks
. any idea on how i can replace the searched word in richtextbox3 with the character next to the searched word in richtextbox1.

`写真 shashin photo`

`雲 Kumo cloud`

`赤 Aka Red`

`赤 Akai Red`

Comment: @RDixon I edited my answer to add the kanji to rtb3.  I wasn't sure if you'll have search words the may be contained in other words, so I didn't add validation to see if it finds a whole word or part of a word, but this should give you a hand in the right direction.

Comment: What kind of string are you putting in rtb3?  The edits to my code show you how to copy just the kanji from the string.  The statement RichTextBox3.Text = line.Split()(0) replaces the text in rtb3 with the kanji.

Comment: i will show you a photo of what i'm working with .
how can i show you this photo ?
when i type a word RTB1 displays the word , RTB2 searches for the word ,RTB3 shoes the character equivalent to the text in RTB1 .

in RTB2 there is a list of characters words that can be searched and  their meaning . example `雲 Kumo cloud`

there can be many words named "Kumo" with different characters 

how can i replace the text in BTB3 with the character 雲  when the replacement function i use is `RichTextBox3.Text = String.Concat(RichTextBox3.Text.Remove(RichTextBox3.Text.Length - lastWord.Length), "雲")`

Comment: I'm not sure about images, you'll probably have to click the help link when you're adding a comment.  If rtb3 is only showing the kanji you don't need to use replace, just a straight rtb3.text = "雲", replaces any text in rtb3 with "雲".  unless there is more your not saying.  Since your original question is answered, you probably should start a new one, and show more code to exactly illustrate the relationship between the 3 rtb's

Comment: Here it is 
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903640/text-replacement-using-search)